# Build Approaches for patches using Git

Tags: git, version-control, build, git-patch

I am new to Git and I have to setup the build process for my account

For full builds I can do `git clone`

However for 'patch builds' I need to 'pull' the last known good code + code changed for that patch

Example

```
a.c  v1.0 - full build
a.c  v1.1 - extract v1.0 (last known good code) + extract delta (v1.1 in this case)
a.c  v1.2 - extract **till** v1.1 (last known good code) + extract delta (v1.2)
```

What are the best build approaches using Git to deploy build and deploy 'patches'?

Suggestions and links will be very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the [Git Flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) model good for working with releases and providing patches. You work with a stable `master` branch and all other work is done in branches. Hot fixes (I guess similar to your 'patches') are part of the model, allowing you to use a stable release (as per a Git tag) and then providing a fix for that release.

Here's another list with a comparison of various branching model: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow

I'm not entirely sure about your question with regards to the 'extract delta', but I guess the use of Git branches and tags is really what you're looking for. You would create tags for `v1.0`, `v1.1`, etc. and then use branches based off these tags for applying the patches.

Comment: I went through the blogs and it serves my purpose, thanks for providing URLs